# Store output of system(file) command as a string in C

Tags: c++, c

To get the type of file we can execute the command

```
system("file --mime-type -b filename");
```

The output displays in to terminal.But could not store the file type using the command

```
char file_type[40] = system("file --mime-type -b filename");
```

So how to store file type as a string using system(file) function.

Comment: return value of system() will be -1 or status of command execution only.

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `popen` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  FILE *fp;
  char file_type[40];

  fp = popen("file --mime-type -b filename", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
      printf("Failed to run command\n" );
      exit -1;
  }

  while (fgets(file_type, sizeof(file_type), fp) != NULL) {
      printf("%s", file_type);
  }

  pclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(file_type)-1` is bogus; `sizeof file_type` is good enough. (fgets always results in a nul-terminated string) BTW: file_type is not initialised. Note: you don't need the parens

Answer (score 4):

See the man page of `system`: It does not return the output of the command executed (but an errorcode or the return value of the command).

What you want is `popen`. It return a `FILE*` which you can use to read the output of the command (see `popen` man page for details).

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm the first and easiest way that comes to my mind for achieving what you want would be to redirect the output to a temp-file and then read it into a char buffer.

```
system("file --mime-type -b filename > tmp.txt");
```

after that you can use `fopen` and `fscanf` or whatever you want to read the content of the file.

Ofcourse, youl'll have the check the return value of [system()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) before attempting to read the temp-file.