# Execute jar file with arguments from c++ and store output

Tags: java, c++, visual-c++, popen

I'm developing a project in visual c++ and at some point in code I need to execute some java jar program with some arguments and store it's output into a string
So the code I execute in CMD and it works is:

```
java -jar weka.jar something.arff
```

And I get some text returned to the command prompt

I want to do the same thing with c++ and store the output into a string variable

I tried using `system` function, but as far as I know it's impossible to store output using that one
I also tried using `_popen`, ( it did work with commands like dir etc...) but it didn't return any output when using the command provided above

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output

Comment: thank you. Like said, I've already used _popen with this jar, but it didn't return any text

Comment: How about you redirect the standard output to a file 'java -jar weka.jar something.arff > out' and the read from that file.

Comment: hmm I tried it with system() and now I've got another problem. It says: java is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: @tadoman Can you run Java through a normal console?