# capture buffer output from a c++ system() command

Tags: c++, system, cout

How would I capture the output from a php script that I run at the command line and store it to an array in c++?
i.e.

```
system('php api/getSome.php');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run an external program from C and parse its output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally popen() is preferred when you need to IO between your parent and child  process. It uses the C based FILE stream. It is a wrapper around the same low level intrinsics that also make up system(), namely fork + execl, but unlike system(), popen() opens a pipe and dups stdin/out to a stream for reading and writing.

```
FILE *p = popen("ping www.google.com", "r");
```

Then read from it like a file.

Answer (score 1):

`system` can't give output to your program. You should redirect the command output to a file, like in `php api/getSome.php > somefile` and read this file from your program, or you should use a proper function that can give you the command output, like `popen`.

Comment: In this particular case, I would really like to capture it in memory first for a string match. Speed is a big deal here. The fewer processes to get the string, the better.

Answer (score 1):

from the man page:

> system()  executes  a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c command.

Just use the shell redirection facility to dump the output of the command in a file:

```
 system("php api/getSome.php > output.txt 2> error.txt");
```

The above will give send the standard output in *output.txt* and the error output in *error.txt*.