# Output of the Linux System Call in C program

Tags: c, linux, unix, system

I want to manipulate the output of the ls -al command in my C program.
Is there a way to do it ?

```
int main()
{
    int return_value;
    return_value = system("ls -al ");
    return return_value;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run an external program from C and parse its output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output)

Answer (score 2):

You need a pipe to the process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{ 

  FILE *fp;
  char output[1024];

  fp = popen("/bin/ls -al", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
    exit(1);

  while (fgets(output, 1023, fp) != NULL) 
    printf("%s", output);

  pclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: On failure of  `popen` better do `if (fp==NULL) { perror("popen"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: I like this solution better than saving it a file and opening the file

Answer (score 1):

You could use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) on `/bin/ls` as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31671088/841108) by Baris Demiray.

But in your particular case (getting the files in a directory), you don't really need to start some external process running `ls`,  you could simply use [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) & [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) to read the directory entries, and use [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) on each of them (you'll build the path using [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html)). See also [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html), [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Notice that the [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) is a very poorly named [standard C library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) function. It is not a direct [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (they are listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...), but uses [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html), etc...