# how does the function system() work in c++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand system calls made in c++ using system("some command"). here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Hello ";
  system("./pause");
  cout << "World";
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

the executable "pause" is created from the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"enter any key to continue\n";
    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

I get the following output

```
enter any key to continue
1
Hello World
```

Can someone please explain the output to me? I was expecting this -

```
Hello
enter any key to continue
1
World
```

Comment: Your expectation is because of `std::cout` buffering, it is not related to system. If you change `cout << "Hello ";` to `cout << "Hello" << endl;` you should see what you expected.

Comment: Note that the name "system call" is already taken by [another concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).

Answer (score 6):

It's probably not a case of system call but output stream buffering.

`cout << "xxx"` does not necessary outputs something, so program called by `system` can be executed before `cout` flushes it buffer to console.

try adding `cout.flush()` after `cout << "Hello"` or write `cout << "Hello" << flush`

also: `cout << endl` automagically calls `flush`

Comment: I wouldn't call it "automagically" since it's very explicitly defined to call `flush`

Comment: @JonathanWakely for person who start working with C++ streams it seems as little magic, as many people think, that `std::endl` is a `std::string` with `"\n"` inside. 'automagic' was referring to 'calling function without () visible'. Maybe not best words :)

Comment: Ah ok, then I guess it does seem like magic from that perspective :)

Answer (score 6):

`system` runs a command in a shell. But your problem is not with `system` but with `cout`. `cout` is line-buffered, ie. it won't flush (write out) its data until a new line character is encountered. You need to flush it explicitely with `cout << flush`.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for the particular behavior that you observe seems to be just `cout` buffering: the `Hello` is not printed immediately, instead held in a buffer until `endl` is output (or the buffer is filled completely, or you explicitly call `flush()`). This is in no way related to a `system()` call.

A simpler example:

```
cout << "Hello";
sleep(10);
cout << "World";
```

Both words will appear at the same time, not with a 10 seconds delay.

Comment: There's another case apart from `endl` or filling the buffer that flushes it: calling `flush` (which is what `endl` does).

Answer (score 4):

The answer on "how does `system` library function works?" is usually operating system specific. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31671209/841108) for a Linux point of view. Notice that `system` is *not* a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) and there is a priori no relation between using [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) and having `cout` buffer being flushed.

You should flush the stdout before calling `system`

```
 cout << "Hello " << flush;
```

or preferably

```
 cout << "Hello " << endl;
```

The behavior you are observing is because `cout` is *buffered* and you forgot to flush the buffer.

Comment: my question has more to do with the sequence of execution of code. "hello" should have been printed first, followed by the system call and then world