# How to store strings from system function

Tags: c, system

I would like to know if there is a way to store the things that system prints out when you call some function from it for e.g. i want my program to read my Wi-Fi key/everything that comes out of console and store it in a .txt file.Is that possible? If not is printing out strings from system possible?

Here is the code for printing out the contents:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    system("netsh wlan show profile wifi name key=clear");



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: redirecting the output string to a file ptr would do the trick

Comment: Will try it thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: On POSIX systems you might want to use [popen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html); while `system` is standardized by C, how the command is executed is not and is operating system specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run an external program from C and parse its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output)

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. Use a library for what you actually want to do with that call and call the functions directly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out using a much simpler way than @Ratul Sharker and @Basile Straynkevitch suggested. The solution is using `>` in the system, but you must have a .txt file before compilation(might figure out a way for the program to write the file)

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    system("netsh wlan show profile wifi name key=clear > C:\\somepath\\name.txt");



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using popen() seems more elegant to me, because it avoids the need for a temporary file, and doesn't rely on particular shell behaviour. Also it avoid the extra memory overhead of loading a shell.