# Detecting current gcc installation

Tags: gcc, command-line, path, installation

In the sake of automatically-detecting native GCC installation from within a program, I would like to get the current path to gcc.exe or its root folder.
But when I type `gcc -print-prog-name=gcc` it simply prints back `gcc` which is obviously not what I was expecting.

How do I use gcc or other components supposedly installed on the system alongside gcc to retrieve the path to the gcc installation or executable?

Comment: Two questions there: para 1 and para 2. Best to ask one question at a time on
SO since folks who can't answer all will probably not answer any. That's
certainly where I am since it's quite unclear what you are asking in para 2.

Comment: @MikeKinghan Thanks for the note, is it better now?

Comment: Actually `set` and `echo %PATH%` will not work, because the gcc installation is usually in PATH and from there one program cannot guess which path is to gcc.exe

Comment: Yes. Just one question after all ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linux at least, the "native GCC installation" might reasonably be
interpreted as *the GCC installation that is invoked through* `/usr/bin/gcc`.
But on that interpretation, there can be no doubt about its installation
path.

Whenever you invoke `gcc`, if such a program is found at all, it is
simply the first program called `gcc` that that is found in one of the
directories listed in the value of environment variable `PATH`, *in the
environment of the invocation*. True on Linux and other Unix-like OSes.
True on Windows.

Imagine that `gcc` had an option `--whereami` that made it print its installation
path on the standard output. The answer you will get will be the answer
given by the first installation of `gcc` that is found in the operative `PATH` at
the time of invocation. There might be any number of GCC installations on
a system each of which will yield a different answer for `gcc --whereami` whenever
that installation is the first to be discovered in the operative `PATH`.

Selection of different GCC installations via different `PATH` settings is
commonplace on Windows, where the notion of "the native installation of GCC"
has no meaning. But it is applicable on Linux too and sometimes used. The point is: *no
matter what command you run to find out where `gcc` is installed, any
answer you get is in principle dependent on the operative* `PATH` -
unless you run the command with an absolute filename:

```
/usr/bin/gcc --whereami
```

which of course amounts to deciding the answer before you ask the question.

The only cross-platform method by which you can discover the directory from
which `gcc` will be run, if at all, by a command `gcc ...`, is to get the
operative `PATH` (programmatically, use [`getenv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getenv.html)),
parse out the the directories it contains left to right and for successive
directories query the filesystem for the existence of an executable `gcc`
within it, stopping when you find one.

And since this can only give an answer *for the operative* `PATH`,
and since the value of `PATH` needs parsed differently on Windows and
Unix-like OSes, you might just as well invoke the OS-specific utility that does the same
thing.

Unix-like:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Windows:

```
C:\>where gcc
C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
```

And note that in the Windows case, I needed to select my `mingw-w64` terminal environment *to get an answer*.

To execute commands and get their output programmatically, see [How can I run an external program from C and parse its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43116/1362568). On Windows, call [`_popen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen)
instead of `popen`.

Comment: Thank you, good answer.
I can write a library that defines "where" or "which" depending on OS or a library that parses environment variables. Why using `_popen` though? I always used `popen` and didn't really notice any problem