# How to implement shell output as a input of C language?

Tags: c, shell, unix

For example, Guess I have a compiled c program,  named as 'binaryOutput'.
And in Unix environment, [root@blablabla ~ ] ./binaryOutput print out some result like this 
[0] [1] [0] [1] [1]

I want to using these result as the input of another c file.

In C lanugage, I can run the file.

```
system("./binaryOutput") ;
```

After the code, I want to add the numbers as an array's input.
How can I do it?

Comment: You should look into `popen()` from here: https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/FUNCTIONS/popen.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run an external program from C and parse its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output)

Comment: Would (from a shell): `./binaryOutput|myprog` be acceptable?  In `myprog` you just read `stdin`.  It is the simplest way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

popen example. You can get the output of the command.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE *fp=NULL;
  char line[1024];
  if ( (fp=popen("ls", "r"))==NULL )
  {
    return -1;
  }
  while( fgets(line, 1023, fp)!=NULL )
  {
    printf("read from popen:%s", line);
  }
  pclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you also describe how your code works? It looks like your program collects dir listing. That's not what OP is looking for. The question asks about executing any executables. Not a specific unix command. So tell us the generic approach.

Comment: replace "ls" to what you want. "./binaryOutput"

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin `ls` _is_ part of the set "any executables".

Comment: `fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)` -- there is no reason to reduce the `size` parameter to `fgets` by `1` as you do for `scanf` *field-width* modifier.

Comment: @Michael Walz I was unaware you have to figure out what 'set' does an input belongs to, then check if that 'set' covers your desired input. Would it not be more helpful to just mention `your command goes here`? I'm only pointing out ways to be more clear to OP's query.