# Redirect output of command line to a variable in C

Tags: c, system, system-calls, popen, fgets

Is there a way to redirect output of a command line which returns integer as an output to a variable in C?

for example, if the command is "cmd", then is there a way to redirect its output (an integer) and store it in variable in C?
I tried using popen and fgets but it seems to be working only with characters. Any suggestions?

Comment: please show what you have tried

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output

Comment: There's a lot of missing detail here.  I don't know what "output of a command line" means.  Have you done some research in "inter-process communication in c?"  Or perhaps creating a pipe?

Comment: You already have the answer. You only need to convert the `string` to an `int`. You could use `sscanf()` for that.

Answer (score 3):

It works perfectly fine with popen and fgets:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *cmd = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "echo 42";
    char buf[32];
    FILE *fp = popen(cmd, "r");
    if( fp == NULL ){
        perror("popen");
        return 1;
    }
    if( fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp) == buf ){
        int v = strtol(buf, NULL, 10);
        printf("read: %d\n", v);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May be worth a note to "adjust `buf` size as needed". (apparent to the experienced, but may not be immediately so to new user that enters `cat some/long/hairy/path.../../..file_w_int.txt`)

Comment: You could even use `fscanf()` for this and get rid of the buffer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a character string from the **standard input**, you could use [fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) and then use [atoi](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) to convert the input to an integer.

If you want to convert the output of a command, let's say `ls` and store the output of the command to a variable, you could learn about [fork](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fork), [dup2](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dup2), [pipe](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe), and [exec](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) function family.

More about this topic on this tutorial : [Capture the output of a child in C](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/capture_the_output_of_a_child_process_in_c.html). This tutorial also provide an example with `popen` if you want to keep things "high level".

Answer (score 0):

Here is an even simpler example using `popen()` and `fscanf()`:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = popen("date '+%s'", "r");
    long seconds;
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "popen failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    if (fscanf(fp, "%ld", &seconds) == 1) {
        printf("epoch seconds: %ld\n", seconds);
        pclose(fp);
        return 0;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid program output\n");
        pclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
}
```